# Hibernate Search, Infinispan, jgroups, Wildfly cluster integration configuration

Tags: java, wildfly, hibernate-search, infinispan, jgroups

I am trying to config a jgroups, infinispan, hibernate search cluster on wildfly. I have two seperated archives in Netbeans, one war and one ejb jar. So I put the ejb as a dependency in the war and then push only the war into wildfly 10.0.0. The thing is that the jndi way did not work so luckily I saw this question. Now I 'm trying to configure it with the xml configuration file, but I still always fall into a  **com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed**. I tried to put the xml configuration file in src, WEB-INF, META-INF, but I 'm stuck at the same exception.

I already check these([Configuring Infinispan CacheProvider in Seam 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508517/configuring-infinispan-cacheprovider-in-seam-2-3), ["experimental" status of JGroups Master/Slave backend for hibernate search and infinispan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986526/experimental-status-of-jgroups-master-slave-backend-for-hibernate-search-and-i), [InfinispanDirectoryProvider with Wildfly 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688122/infinispandirectoryprovider-with-wildfly-10-1/47755333#47755333)) with no results.

This is how I declare the property in the persistence.xml

`property name="hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename" value="infinispan-config.xml"`

> [Server:server-one] Caused by:
>   org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed [Server:server-one]
>   at
>   org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:110)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.hibernate.search.impl.InfinispanConfigurationParser.parseFile(InfinispanConfigurationParser.java:57)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.hibernate.search.impl.InfinispanConfigurationParser.parseFile(InfinispanConfigurationParser.java:42)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.hibernate.search.impl.DefaultCacheManagerService.start(DefaultCacheManagerService.java:79)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.hibernate.search.engine.service.impl.StandardServiceManager$ServiceWrapper.startService(StandardServiceManager.java:303)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.hibernate.search.engine.service.impl.StandardServiceManager$ServiceWrapper.startVirtual(StandardServiceManager.java:268)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.hibernate.search.engine.service.impl.StandardServiceManager.createAndCacheWrapper(StandardServiceManager.java:205)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.hibernate.search.engine.service.impl.StandardServiceManager.requestService(StandardServiceManager.java:87)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.hibernate.search.spi.InfinispanDirectoryProvider.initialize(InfinispanDirectoryProvider.java:66)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64)
>   [Server:server-one]     ... 28 more [Server:server-one] Caused by:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Stream closed [Server:server-one]
>   at
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:550)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:605)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:618)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:324)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>       __redirected.__XMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(__XMLInputFactory.java:134)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:116)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:105)
>   [Server:server-one]     ... 37 more [Server:server-one] Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Stream closed [Server:server-one]     at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
>   [Server:server-one]     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown
>   Source) [Server:server-one]     at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) [Server:server-one] 
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(StreamBootstrapper.java:478)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.resolveStreamEncoding(StreamBootstrapper.java:302)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.io.StreamBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(StreamBootstrapper.java:166)
>   [Server:server-one]     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:545)
>   [Server:server-one]     ... 43 more

Any new ideas?

Infinispan 8.2.4, Hibernate Search 5.6.4, Wildfly 10.0.0, Hibernate OGM 5.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such errors are caused by having bundled an incompatible version; since you mention `Hibernate Search 5.6.4` which is not the version included in `WildFly 10` I guess you're bundling a copy of the library in your application.

You could update the libraries but that requires expert assembly of a custom module; it's best to take one of the existing modules sets as they will have been tested by the respective releasing team (Hibernate/WildFly/Infinispan).

The easiest is to use the Hibernate Search version included in WildFly, as described in the [Hibernate Search documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-deploy-on-wildfly).

For WildFly 10 that's Hibernate Search version `5.5.1` as you can see in [the tagged sources](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/10.0.0.Final/pom.xml#L148).

Next get the Infinispan release which is aiming at compatibility with this specific version of the app server; you need the "WildFly/EAP modules" from the [Infinispan downloads](http://infinispan.org/download/).

Alternatively use the modules included by any Hibernate Search release as described in [section 3.10.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_update_and_activate_latest_hibernate_search_version_in_wildfly) but these don't include Infinispan, you'll have to fetch a compatible version from Infinispan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Well actually yes, messing up with modules other than wildfly's built in was rough. I am using OGM too and in the compatibility matrix of hibernate mentions about hibernate search 5.6. That's why I stick in Search 5.6 (wrong?). My issue is fixed. In netbeans, config had to be placed exactly in the resources folder, not src, not META-INF(at least to access it from the persistence.xml). For people that may have similar problems, after fixing directory, be careful with the schema declarations (<infinispan xmlns:xsi = ... ><cache-container>) to be at the proper form.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We're working now on replacing the module zip files with "feature pack"; they can express transitive dependencies and have several other benefits. It should make things easier! Watch our blog for announcements: http://in.relation.to/